# Increment operator in PHP + JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, increment

The PHP increment operator isnt working in my code, i dont know why. Here it is my code:

```
for(var j=0; j<=COUNTLatitud;j++) {
<?php  $incremento=0; ?>
valor1=<?php echo (float)$Latitud[$incremento];?>;
valor2=<?php echo (float)$Longitud[$incremento];?>; 
point = new google.maps.LatLng(<valor1,valor2);         
<?php $incremento=$incremento+1; ?>     
iconoMarcador = new google.maps.MarkerImage( 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/d4x1b4qtqhbvfwn/office-building.png', new google.maps.Size(32, 37), new google.maps.Point(0,0), new google.maps.Point(9, 34) );
    if( google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation( point, miPoligono ) ) {                 
        marcador = new google.maps.Marker( {
        map: miMapa,
        position: point,
        icon: iconoMarcador
        } );
    }
}
```

Im using JavaScript + PHP, when i make a console.log(j) the for is working properly.

(The variables are declare above)

Any leads? i want to cry.

Comment: You cannot put PHP inside of your JavaScript. .You *CAN* use PHP to produce JavaScript. In your example, you will get JavaScript code without PHP in it. That code will run. It will not run back to the server in each time through the loop to update $incremento. You really need to step back and concentrate on the difference between server-side and client-side scripting.

Comment: If you need to receive or send data from/to server use ajax (php on server, javascript on client's browser). If not, you can probably do this in pure javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i managed my problem this way:

```
function marcadores(){
            var valor1=new Array();
            var valor2=new Array();
            var point;
            var marcador;
            var iconoMarcador;
            var arrayLat=<?php echo json_encode($Latitud);?>;
            var arrayLon=<?php echo json_encode($Longitud);?>;
            for(var j=0; j<=COUNTLatitud;j++) {
                point = new google.maps.LatLng(arrayLat[j],arrayLon[j]);
                iconoMarcador = new google.maps.MarkerImage( 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/d4x1b4qtqhbvfwn/office-building.png', new google.maps.Size(32, 37), new google.maps.Point(0,0), new google.maps.Point(9, 34) );
                    if( google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation( point, miPoligono ) ) {
                        marcador = new google.maps.Marker( {
                        map: miMapa,
                        position: point,
                        icon: iconoMarcador
                    } );
                }




            }
        }
```

I hope help some one :)